# how to add click element on desktop and mobile version

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I have this in CSS**

```js
function focusCard(element) {
  element.getElementsByClassName("front")[0].classList.toggle("show");
  element.getElementsByClassName("back")[0].classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 270px;
  height: 170px;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 270px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: #778da9;
  transform: perspective(800px);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box:hover .front,
.show {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 270px;
  height: 170px;
  background: #415a77;
  transform: perspective(800px) rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  flex-direction: column;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.box:hover .back,
.show {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="questions">
    <div class="">
      <div class="box" onclick="focusCard(this)">
        <div class="front center">
          <h2>Front #1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="back center">
          <p>Back #2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On desktop devices works fine but on mobile devices doesnt work properly.
On mobile devices, it only works when I click on the front. Back appears, but does not go back to front when you click back. can anyone help me this problem?

**Thanks for all tips & advice**

Comment: There is no reliable hover on mobile. You'll have to define how it should work on touch and handle the touch-events in JS.

Comment: As @niorad said, there's no *real* hover mechanism on touch devices so you should consider looking at the [Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) to get your task done.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having has nothing to do with mobile event registration. The mobile can also handle `click` event without problems. It works fine for pc mainly because of `:hover` pseudo class.

It would make more sense that putting `.show` on `.box` instead of its children. You may also consider putting `perspective` on `.box`.

On top of that, you should add `:hover` only for a device that has a cursor, since after tapping the element on mobile, the `:hover` kept activated until you tap somewhere else.

```css
/* make hover only works for pc */
@media (hover: hover) {
  .box:hover .front {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
      
  .box:hover .back {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}
```

Here's a cleaned-up version for what you might want to achieve:

```js
function focusCard(element) {
  element.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 270px;
  height: 170px;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 270px;
  height: 170px;
  background-color: #778da9;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 270px;
  height: 170px;
  background: #415a77;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  flex-direction: column;
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}

/* make hover only works for pc */
@media (hover: hover) {
  .box:hover .front {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
  }
  
  .box:hover .back {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
  }
}

.show .front {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.show .back{
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="questions">
    <div class="">
      <div class="box" onclick="focusCard(this)">
        <div class="front center">
          <h2>Front #1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="back center">
          <p>Back #2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```